# Center and radius of sphere

Tags: syntax

What is the `Mathematica` equivalent(s) of the Wolfram Alpha command to get the center and radius of a sphere given by an expression, e.g. (in Wolfram Alpha);

```
x^2+y^2+z^2+8x-6y-4z-7=0 calculate center and radius
```

which returns 6 and $(-4,3,2)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out if you just minimize the lhs of the equation, you get $-r^2$ and the centers immediately, and $r=\sqrt{|-36|}=6$:

```
Minimize[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + 8 x - 6 y - 4 z - 7, {x, y, z}]
(* result: {-36, {x -> -4, y -> 3, z -> 2}} *)
```

Why does this work? The value of $s(x,y,z)=(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2+(z-z_0)^2-r^2$ is precisely $0$ on the sphere surface, positive on the exterior of the sphere, and negative on the interior. It's easy to see that $s(x_0,y_0,z_0)=-r^2$ and the gradient $\nabla s(x,y,z)=2 (x - x_0)\mathbf{i}+ 2 (y - y_0)\mathbf{j}+ 2 (z - z_0)\mathbf{k}$ is zero at the center and grows outwards in all directions.

---

**Note:** I didn't consider this as your equation has no leading coefficients of $x^2,y^2,z^2$ which means the above solution works. However, **@yarchik** pointed out a problem if the sphere equation is scaled and starts with $k x^2+ky^2+kz^2+...$ where $k\neq1$ then `Minimize` will produce the correct centers but gives a minimum value of $-kr^2$. So you will need to take this into account, for example here's the same sphere from a proportional equation:

```
s = Expand[(x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + 8 x - 6 y - 4 z - 7)/100];
m = Minimize[s, {x, y, z}]; (* returns {-(9/25), {x -> -4, y -> 3, z -> 2}} *)
centers = {x, y, z} /. Last[m]; (* {-4, 3, 2} *)
radius = Sqrt[Abs[First[m]/Coefficient[s, x^2]]]; (* 6 *)
```

---

Alternatively, if you can find 4 points on the sphere surface (using `FindInstance`) then that's all you need to get the centers and the radius:

```
eq = x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + 8 x - 6 y - 4 z - 7;
sphere = (x - c1)^2 + (y - c2)^2 + (z - c3)^2 - r^2;
points = {x, y, z} /. FindInstance[eq == 0, {x, y, z}, Reals, 4];
system = ((sphere - eq) == 0 && r > 0 /. {x -> #[[1]], y -> #[[2]], z -> #[[3]]}) & /@ points;
Solve[system, {c1, c2, c3, r}]
```

Comment: Your first solution is not correct. The same result should hold for a rescaled equation. But `Minimize[(x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + 8 x - 6 y - 4 z - 7)/100, {x, y, z}]` yields 3/5 as a radius.

Comment: @yarchik you are right - the centers are correct though and the radius easily follows from that - I will correct the answer. This is only relevant if the x^2, y^2,z^2 have leading coefficients